# Why is my Blazor App stopping with an Object reference not set to an instance of an object?

Tags: blazor, lifecycle

I installed the new version of VS2022 and I have had nothing but trouble since. I restored my app and rolled back the installation but I'm still having the problem. I need to know more about the initialization of the app to find the issue. It's a null reference exception so it's not finding something. This is a Blazor Server App. Here are the details:

Here is where the error is:

```
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

Here is the detailed exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException
HResult=0x80004003
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
StackTrace:
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing.Router.Refresh(Boolean isNavigationIntercepted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing.Router.<SetParametersAsync>d__56.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.HandleExceptionViaErrorBoundary(Exception error, ComponentState errorSourceOrNull)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToPendingTasks(Task task, ComponentState owningComponentState)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SupplyCombinedParameters(ParameterView directAndCascadingParameters)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(ParameterView parameters)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 newFrameIndex)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 newFrameIndex)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Int32 componentId, ArrayRange`1 oldTree, ArrayRange`1 newTree)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, Exception& renderFragmentException)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessPendingRender()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToRenderQueue(Int32 componentId, RenderFragment renderFragment)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.<RunInitAndSetParametersAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.HandleExceptionViaErrorBoundary(Exception error, ComponentState errorSourceOrNull)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToPendingTasks(Task task, ComponentState owningComponentState)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SupplyCombinedParameters(ParameterView directAndCascadingParameters)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(ParameterView parameters)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.<RenderRootComponentAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.<CreateInitialRenderAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.<RenderComponentAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.<>c__11`1.<<InvokeAsync>b__11_0>d.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.StaticComponentRenderer.<PrerenderComponentAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.<PrerenderedServerComponentAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.<RenderComponentAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.ComponentTagHelper.<ProcessAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.<<RunAsync>g__Awaited|0_0>d.MoveNext()
at ISInventory_Server.Pages.Pages__Host.<ExecuteAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in \\sofdata01\crossste$\repos\ISInventory\ISInventory_Server\Pages\_Host.cshtml:line 11

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]
ISInventory_Server.Pages.Pages__Host.ExecuteAsync() in _Host.cshtml
```

Can someone provide some clues as to where this incident might be occurring? I'm just not that familiar with the initialization process to know what might be happening. I have also restored from a git backup from a few days ago and it worked so this indicates to me I have something in the code that is not configured properly and that it probably was not the VS 2022 update..

Comment: The second line `SetParametersAsync` suggests the problem is in setting the parameters on a component on the landing page when it's being preloaded.  Either build in some Error boundaries or remove stuff until you find the culprit.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I had to go back to a prior commit.  Neve did find out what the issue was.